# Change column type to Date in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I had added new table to my Power Bi file that contains a column with date with the following format: `dd/MM/yyyy` for example: 17/08/2017.

In power Bi this column is Text type, and when I try to convert to date it came with the following error:

```
DataFormat.Error: We couldn't parse the input provided as a Date value.
Details:
    17/08/2017
```

how can I change its type or format this text on new column and change the type if possible?

Comment: Can you give us a copy of that column? Maybe have a extra character or something that are not allowing the conversion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try altering the Regional Settings for the Current File to a country where `dd/MM/yyyy` is the standard date format. Like the Netherlands (or maybe your own country).

Choose [Options and settings > Options] on the File-tab. When you're done, refresh.

[image]

---

If changing the settings doesn't work for you, you can use the Power Query Editor to split the date column and then merge in the correct order. Perform the following steps:

1. Select the date column and use Split Column (Transform tab). Split by delimiter [/] and select [Each occurance of the delimiter]
2. Merge the three columns again by using Merge Columns. The columns will merge in the order that you select them. For the separator choose custom and type /
3. Change the datatype to Date

This part of the script should look somthing like this:

```
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Previous step", {{"Date", type text}}, "en-US"), "Date", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("/", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Date.1", "Date.2", "Date.3"}),
#"Merged Columns2" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{"Date.2", "Date.1", "Date.3"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("/", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
#"Changed Type5" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Merged Columns2",{{"Merged", type date}})
```

Comment: Thanks! the first solution of changing the region worked.

Comment: What else could be effected by changing the Regional Settings?

Comment: See the image in my answer: numbers, dates and times in imported text. For example:  `123,456.78` is English (VS) format. In the Netherlands that would be `123.456,78`